# selenium-side-runner - Validation Error: Test environment jest-environment-selenium cannot be found

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-side-runner

I run my selenium tests from shell, everything works as it should!

```sh
$ selenium-side-runner --server http://chromedriver:4444/wd/hub --capabilities "browserName=chrome" /app/tests/proxy.lucky_app.side
info:    Running /app/tests/proxy.lucky_app.side
 PASS  ./DefaultSuite.test.js
  Default Suite
    ✓ test frontend (1282ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.329s
Ran all test suites.
```

However, if I execute the same command from a shell script `test.sh`, I get the below error. What causes it and how can I fix it ?

**tests.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

selenium-side-runner --server http://chromedriver:4444/wd/hub --capabilities "browserName=chrome" /app/tests/proxy.lucky_app.side
```

**Error**

```sh
$ /app/scripts/test.sh
info:    Running /app/tests/proxy.lucky_app.side
● Validation Error:

  Test environment jest-environment-selenium cannot be found. Make sure the testEnvironment configuration option points to an existing node module.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html
```

Answer (score 0):

## Context

The reason for my error and this flaky behavior was explicit reference to the latest release of `selenium-webdriver` - at the moment of writing this answer, it's `selenium-webdriver@4.1.1`

**package.json** - error

```
    "dependencies": {
        "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
        "jest-environment-selenium": "^2.1.2",
        "selenium-side-runner": "^3.5.4",
        "selenium": "^2.20.0",
        "selenium-webdriver": "^4.1.1"
    }
}
```

## Solution

Fix, was to remove `selenium-webdriver` from `package.json`.

**package.json** - no errors

```
    "dependencies": {
        "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
        "jest-environment-selenium": "^2.1.2",
        "selenium-side-runner": "^3.5.4",
        "selenium": "^2.20.0"
    }
}
```